# Invalid React hook when unit testing components using withStyles (material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm trying to unit test a component that is using withStyles from material-ui.  I have am defining the style below.

```
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const myStyle = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    root: {
        display: 'flex'
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    drawer: {
        width: 240
    }
});

export function useStyles() {
    return makeStyles(myStyle);
}
```

it is being consumed by a component called MainPage as follows

```
export const MainPage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <DynamicFormWrapper
                baseUrl={'https://.......'}
                classes={classes()}
            />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    );
};
```

I have a component further down the tree that relies on that style that looks like this

```
type FormProps = {
    names: string[];
} & WithStyles;

export class SideMenu extends React.Component<FormProps> {
    private names: string[];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.names= props.names;
    }

    render() {
        //omitted
    }
}
```

When trying to test that component, i need to pass in the style as a prop, and am trying to do that like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { SideMenu } from '../src/components/SideMenu';
import { useStyles } from '../src/js/styles'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('SideMenu', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const style = useStyles();
        wrapper = shallow(<SideMenu names={['test1', 'test2', 'test3']} classes={style()} />);
    });

    it('Should render', () => {
        expect(wrapper)
    });
});
```

when running the tests, this will throw an Invalid Hook error

```
 Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following yada yada

      16 |     beforeEach(() => {
      17 |         const style = useStyles();
    > 18 |         wrapper = shallow(<SideMenu names={['test1', 'test2', 'test3']} classes={style()} />);
         |                                                                                  ^ 
      19 |     });
      20 |
      21 |      it('Should render', () => {
```

I'm able to fix these when I run into them with normal components, but can't seem to get around it in a unit test like this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `classes={style()}` to `classes={style}`.

Comment: I have tried that, and it makes typescript angry with compile errors like the one below.

Type '(props?: any) => Record<"root" | "content" | "drawer", string>' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
  Index signature is missing in type '(props?: any) => Record<"root" | "content" | "drawer", string>'.

I have tried to mess around with explicitly typing things, but haven't had much luck yet.  Right now I'm working around the issue be re creating the style on my test class, but would rather not rely on duplicating code unnecessarily.

Comment: What is `Record`?

Comment: Record is a type from typescript, it isn't something i've created.